# Unable to get keyboard to show when extending AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I made my own modified version of [DroidParts `ClearableEditText`](https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts-misc/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java), and Android Studio gave me the following error:

> This custom view should extend `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` instead.
>
> In order to support features such as tinting, the appcompat library will automatically load special appcompat replacements for the builtin widgets. However, this does not work for your own custom views.
>
> Instead of extending the android.widget classes directly, you should instead extend one of the delegate classes in `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompat`.

However, when I change my `ClearableEditText` class to extend that one, the keyboard never shows up when I focus the text field.

I know I can just go back to extending `EditText` directly, but I want to do this the recommended way. How can I do that and get the keyboard to show up?

Comment: did you find solution to this?

Comment: @TomasMaksimavicius No, not yet.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you using **super** instead of this() every constructor. I face the same issue with extends AppCompatEditText

working code:

```
public RichEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RichEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RichEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```